# Dropping table makes MySQL hang

Tags: mysql, locks

When I try to drop a table, MySQL hangs. I don't have any other open sessions. How to resolve this? I have waited for 10 hours and the process has not terminated.

Comment: please post the result of SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS if the database is under innodb of course

Comment: looks like the table you are trying to drop is already in use (well, I mean it's been locked by some other process) and hence it's waiting for the process to commit.

Comment: @cool_cs, which mysql version you are running? This looks like a bug in old version of mysql (mysql version: 4.1.22, 4.1.24). see this: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=31937

Comment: Can you run this 2 command and pose the result. 1. `show innodb status\G` and 2. `show processlist`. also, `show open tables;`

Comment: I have posted the output for these commands.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
Waiting for table metadata lock
drop table tableA name

SELECT l1.lat, l1.lon, l2.zipcode FROM tableA l1, tableBl2 where l1.lat = l2.latitude and l1.lon = l2.longitude limit 10
```

If this is your table, see [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/metadata-locking.html)

you have an implicit deadlock. Kill the other transactions to release the drop, or kill the drop to release the other transactions.

You can use [KILL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/kill.html) thread_id, in sql_plus.

---

I'm adding further information since I came up with another interesting experience.

`Metadata` Dead locks may equally happen between a ddl operation on a given table (`drop`, `alter`...) and a **select** query on that table.

Yes, `select`.

So, if you loop over a cursor in mysql (or php, for example with `pdo::fetch`), and you run a ddl statement on the same table(s), you will get a deadlock.

One solution to this atypical scenario is to release the implicit locks with a `commit` statement systematically after any select statement is completely fetched.

Comment: I dropped the table, and now I cannot create a new table as I get the errorcode(28): cannot sync file '..' to disk. I am assuming by dropping the table I would have more free space.

Comment: which file? I think you should restart the server since the lock lasted a long time.

Comment: when i run a really big create table statement with multiple columns i get this error message. by restarting the server do you mean exiting and reconnecting again? how do you explicity restart server?

Comment: restart your server, and then open a new defect in Stack overflow :-)

Comment: I solved it by using `mysqladmin processlist` and `mysqladmin kill` [as shown here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/kill.html). Worked perfectly if your root user has `SUPER`privileges or if logging in with the user that owns the blocking process.

Answer (score 26):

I'm trying easier answer for newbies as i am:

1) run :

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST
```

if you get something like:

```
+----+-----------------+-----------------+--------+------------+-----------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| Id | User            | Host            | db     | Command    | Time      | State                           | Info                                              |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+--------+------------+-----------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
|  4 | event_scheduler | localhost       | NULL   | Daemon     | 580410103 | Waiting on empty queue          | NULL                                              |
| 13 | root            | localhost:50627 | airbnb | Sleep      |     10344 |                                 | NULL                                              |
| 17 | root            | localhost:50877 | NULL   | Query      |      2356 | Waiting for table metadata lock | SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `airbnb`.`characteristics` |
| 18 | root            | localhost:50878 | airbnb | Query      |      2366 | Waiting for table metadata lock | DROP TABLE `airbnb`.`characteristics`             |
| 21 | root            | localhost:51281 | airbnb | Query      |      2305 | Waiting for table metadata lock | SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `airbnb`.`bed_type`        |
| 22 | root            | localhost:51282 | airbnb | Query      |      2301 | Waiting for table metadata lock | SHOW INDEXES FROM `airbnb`.`characteristics`      |
| 23 | root            | localhost:51290 | airbnb | Query      |      2270 | Waiting for table metadata lock | SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `airbnb`.`property_type`   |
| 24 | root            | localhost:51296 | airbnb | Query      |      2240 | Waiting for table metadata lock | SHOW INDEXES FROM `airbnb`.`property_type`        |
| 26 | root            | localhost:51303 | NULL   | Query      |      2212 | Waiting for table metadata lock | SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `airbnb`.`characteristics` |
| 27 | root            | localhost:51304 | NULL   | Query      |      2218 | Waiting for table metadata lock | SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `airbnb`.`bed_type`        |
| 29 | root            | localhost:51306 | NULL   | Query      |      2176 | Waiting for table metadata lock | SHOW INDEXES FROM `airbnb`.`characteristics`      |
| 30 | root            | localhost:51308 | NULL   | Query      |      2122 | Waiting for table metadata lock | DROP TABLE `airbnb`.`characteristics`             |
| 34 | root            | localhost:51312 | NULL   | Query      |      2063 | Waiting for table metadata lock | SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `airbnb`.`characteristics` |
| 35 | root            | localhost:51313 | NULL   | Query      |      2066 | Waiting for table metadata lock | SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `airbnb`.`bed_type`        |
| 39 | root            | localhost:51338 | NULL   | Query      |      2004 | Waiting for table metadata lock | SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `airbnb`.`characteristics` |
| 40 | root            | localhost:51339 | NULL   | Query      |      2008 | Waiting for table metadata lock | SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `airbnb`.`bed_type`        |
| 45 | root            | localhost       | airbnb | Field List |       997 | Waiting for table metadata lock |                                                   |
| 46 | root            | localhost       | airbnb | Field List |       798 | Waiting for table metadata lock |                                                   |
| 53 | root            | localhost       | airbnb | Query      |         0 | starting                        | SHOW PROCESSLIST                                  |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+--------+------------+-----------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

with State : waiting for table metadata lock (as mentioned in official answer)

2) `KILL 13` (13 coresponding to the Id).

If it's indeed a deadlock, all the following processes will continue normally.

Answer (score 12):

Restarting MySQL might not be the prettiest solution but it worked for me:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
mysqladmin drop YOURDATABASE
```

Comment: I dont want to drop database because it would remove privileges to that DB.

Comment: If it happened to anyone in Windows - run services.msc and restart the MySQL process.