# Dropping a large mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with over 3 million records, I tried dropping it in MySQL Workbench, it freezes every-time, I logged into sql command prompt through my shell and did

`drop table table_name`

it froze.

I tried deleting the records in the table

```
Delete from table_name where `ID` > 100000;
```

it froze

I thought maybe I'd let it run for awhile after two hours it's still running:

How can I delete this table?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871388/dropping-table-makes-mysql-hang

Comment: Quick suggestion: try using the mysql (terminal) client, if this happens again, then there is something there. Also, are there any dependencies between this table and some other table?

Comment: @ipinak no there are no foreign key constraints on this table.

Comment: Can't you just `truncate` it?

Comment: I thought that was what I was doing with the delete by ID, but i'll try truncate, thanks.

Comment: If you are using myisam you can just delete the files

Comment: What is the storage engine for the table? MyISAM? InnoDB? something else? If it's InnoDB, and it's not in it's own file (innodb_file_per_table), there's a lot of information to be written to the InnoDB logs, the binary logs, and the InnoDB tablespace to mark the space used by the table as free space. Also, are there any transactions that are holding locks on the table? A `SHOW PROCESSLIST` may give an indication what the session doing the DROP TABLE is doing, or what it's waiting on. A restart of the mysql server would clear outstanding locks, but recovery might take a while.

Comment: This question might be better asked on dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some ideas:

Try removing Indexes

```
 DROP INDEX 'INDEXNAME' ON 'table_name'
```

Then try removing constraints if there are any

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
DROP FOREIGN KEY Foreign_Key_Name
```

and then try dropping it?