# MySQL: Slow Drop table command

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS <myTableName>;
```

however even after several hours it is still running. Any suggestions for a workaround?

Comment: check this thread, maybe you have the same hanging drop table issue [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871388/dropping-table-makes-mysql-hang?rq=1)

Comment: Yes, it will be a locking issue. Check whether you have open/uncommitted trans on that table?

Comment: Note: sometimes this happens with UPDATE statements; see my answer for details.

Answer (score 36):

A better way:

#### Kill all processes that are in the way of a DROP operation

Suppose you want to DROP a table `table` in database `database`

1) Login to mysql in a parallel session, preferably as root.
issue:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

you will see a list of all processes on the db<sup>*</sup>:

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+------+---------------------------------+------------------------------+----------+
| Id    | User      | Host      | db       | Command | Time | State                           | Info                         | Progress |
+-------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+------+---------------------------------+------------------------------+----------+
| 38239 | username  | 10.0.0.1  | database | Sleep   |  591 |                                 | NULL                         |    0.000 |
| 38240 | username  | 10.0.0.1  | database | Sleep   |  590 |                                 | NULL                         |    0.000 |
| 38245 | username  | 10.0.0.1  | database | Query   | 2636 | Waiting for table metadata lock | DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table` |    0.000 |
| 38257 | username  | localhost | database | Query   |    0 | init                            | SHOW PROCESSLIST             |    0.000 |
+-------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------+----------------------+----------+
```

2) If there are any active processes **before** the DROP, you should wait for them to finish (or kill them, if you are sure).

3) Then kill all processes that "Sleep" before your waiting one:

```
KILL 38239;
KILL 38240;
```

4) After that, the blocked process should proceed with the DROP operation.

Waiting before DROP  is a known issue in InnoDB.

---

*Update:* Also noticed this behavior on non-exclusive updates  (updates where number of affected records may vary), such as:

```
# may update any number of customers, from 0 to all
UPDATE customers SET `active` = 'N' WHERE `last-payment-date` < 2018-01-01;
```

Solution is exactly the same.

---

- <sub>The table provided is taken from a real life scenario, data is obfuscated and slightly edited for security and presentation purposes.</sub>

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue and it just solved by restarting the server:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Maybe some lock was being held and the restart released it.